# What are the most and least common kana in Japanese people's last name?

Tags: names, kana

There are 104 kana in Japanese. Literally all of them can be used to spell people's last names. However, some are used more often than others. For example, "た", "だ", "とう", because 田 and 藤 are common kanji in last names. My question is: what kana or kana combination (such as "とう") are more common and what are less common? Is there some kind of frequency list?